# Why click() and evaluate both not working in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code: 
I am trying to login to my linkedln account which is done successfully but i want to go to page that stores my connections and fetch their details but onclick event not working for going to that page. Can anyone help how to proceed?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const C = require('./constants');
const USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#username';
const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#password';
const CTA_SELECTOR = '#app__container > main > div:nth-child(2) > form > 
div.login__form_action_container > button';
let selector= '#ember23';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage- 
  basic_nav-header-signin');
  await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(C.username);
  await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(C.password);
  await page.click(CTA_SELECTOR);
  await page.waitForNavigation();

  await page.evaluate((selector) => document.querySelector(selector).click(), selector); 
  //   await page.click(MY_NETWORK);

  await page.screenshot({path: 'linkedln.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Unrelated, but It seems like you're using a file to store secrets. You should be using environment variables.